# draw multiple lines in line chart dynamically

Tags: javascript, d3.js

I am trying to create a multi-line chart upon [this example](http://bl.ocks.org/d3noob/a22c42db65eb00d4e369), and need to draw multiple lines dynamically based on user selections. The code uses following approach to create the lines:

```
var valueline = d3.svg.line()
  .x(function(d) {
    return x(d.date);
  })
  .y(function(d) {
    return y(d.primary);
  });
```

It then creates calls the `valueline()` to create the paths:

```
svg.append("path")
  .attr("class", "line")
  .attr("d", valueline(data));
```

I am using JSON to render the charts and have a simple array of Objects with key-value pairs:

```
data = [{
      "date": "1-Apr-11",
      "primary": 58.13,
      "secondary": 28.13
    }, {
      "date": "1-May-11",
      "primary": 53.98,
      "secondary": 35.13
    }];
```

[Here is the JSFiddle.](https://jsfiddle.net/sdnyn8uf/)

The current code is only able to plot the `primary` line. Can anyone please suggest a dynamic way to draw multiple lines? I tried to create a second `valueline2()` function to create the second line, and then another `svg.append("path")` with line `valueline2()` to create the path. So the more the lines, the more duplicate code will be there, so I don't think that's a preferable approach. Please help, really stuck with this.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you should not creating duplicates. Note that `valueline` from your example is function which accepts `data` and generates line path (this function is also called *line generator* in API). You can create a function which will return a different function (line generator) per each of your data columns:

```
    // Define the parametric line generator
    var valueline = function(field) { 
      return d3.svg.line()
        .x(function(d) {
        return x(d.date);
      })
        .y(function(d) {
        return y(d[field]);
      });
    };
  ...

      for (let field of ["primary", "secondary"])
      {
        // Add the valueline path.
        svg.append("path")
          .attr("class", "line") 
          // here you constructing specific line generator and pass data to it  
          .attr("d", valueline(field)(data)); 
      }
```

Working example here: https://jsfiddle.net/sdnyn8uf/18/ (sorry, no hoverable points there for the second segment)

Comment: Putting `append()` methods inside loops is a very bad practice. See the D3js multiline chart created by Mike Bostock. He never uses this kind of approach. Anyways, I solved the problem by converting the data to different format (took help from Mike Bostock's multiline chart design).